# CSS menu moving left get zoom in IOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to move my menu to left side on clicking the menu button in responsive view. This working fine in all device except **IOS devices**. In IOS devices on clicking the menu button the menu get zoom in *safari* browser and in *chrome* in moving with jerking(step by step).

```
header {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 transition: 0.8s;
 -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

on clicking

```
  header.mv-menu {
   float: none;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   clear: both;
   left: -71%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
   transition: 1s;
}
```

If I set **position: fixed** to the header, its working fine. But I don't want fixed position, because I have some elements above the menu.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gotf7g4f/6/

Comment: Did you add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> to your <head> tag ?

Comment: please provide demo link.

Comment: Try using `margin-left` instead of `left`

Comment: @Ahsan yes with initial-scale=1

Comment: @sushmit.patil same effect for margin-left also

Comment: @Sami kindly provide demo